# RecyclerView last item blinks every time an item is removed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-cursorloader

I'm using a cursor loader with the `RecyclerView`, and everything else works just fine except every time I remove an item from the RecyclerView, the last item blinks, like this

[last item blinks](https://giphy.com/gifs/145MuS5V7AYrm0)

my code for deletion is

```
public void deleteData(long id){
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(URI, id);
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
}
```

code on swipe:

```
deleteData(viewHolder.getItemId());
```

note that I have another activity that's using the same `RecyclerAdapter`, `ContentProvider` and layout code, even most of the implementations and method approaches are the same, but that one works perfectly without any blinks, so it is a pretty weird situation for me.

Is there a specific reason that can cause this problem? I already tried disabling the animation like

```
recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);
```

or

```
((DefaultItemAnimator) recyclerViewObject.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```

But none of that worked, not to mention that I do want the animations to work.

**Edit**: Break points upload:

onCreate:

> "main@4668" prio=5 tid=0x2 nid=NA runnable
>       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE    at com.jackz314.todo.HistoryActivity.onCreateLoader(HistoryActivity.java:803)
>       at
>   android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createLoader(LoaderManager.java:539)
>       at
>   android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManager.java:548)     at
>   android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManager.java:603)
>       at
>   com.jackz314.todo.HistoryActivity.displayAllNotes(HistoryActivity.java:394)
>       at
>   com.jackz314.todo.HistoryActivity.deleteExpiredNotes(HistoryActivity.java:767)
>       at
>   com.jackz314.todo.HistoryActivity.onCreate(HistoryActivity.java:129)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java:-1)       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)       at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-1)     at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

onDelete(remove item):

> "main@4668" prio=5 tid=0x2 nid=NA runnable java.lang.Thread.State:
>   RUNNABLE    at
>   com.jackz314.todo.HistoryActivity.deleteData(HistoryActivity.java:791)
>       at
>   com.jackz314.todo.HistoryActivity$4.onSwiped(HistoryActivity.java:434)
>       at
>   android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper$4.run(ItemTouchHelper.java:686)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)      at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)       at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-1)     at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Hope those helps

**Edit**: After a little investigation, I found out that the last item didn't actually blink, it seems that the `RecyclerView` first changed it's length/size, cuts off a section that has the equal size as the deleted item(deleting), so that the last item(depending on the size of the deleted item) is not visible for a while, and then the `RecyclerView` deletes the item that's supposed to be deleted at the beginning. I'm still working on it, trying to figure out whether it's because I messed up the order somewhere or it's some other reason.

Comment: I had a similar issue till I added this code my design is RecyclerAdapter DetailsActivity and ListActivity I delete in the Details and tell the List  which is tied to the Adapter code is in Details under btnDelete             ListActivity.removeListRow(position);
// Code line above calls Method in ListActivity to notify recycler view of changes

Comment: do you have code like this in the Activity that deletes the row of data     // This method is called from DetailsActivity and notifies Recycler View that the DB was changed
    // and the method makes the same changes to the Recycler View kind of a sync of DB and Recycler View
    public static void removeListRow(int position) {
        dbList.remove(position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, dbList.size());
    }

Comment: I don't have code that deletes the rows of data because everything is automatically handled by the `cursorLoader`, and that's why it's so confusing for me. I'll try your method later, thanks.

Comment: @Grendel, can you explain more about how you added the `ListActivity.removeListRow(position)` thing? I figured it might solve the problem, but don't know how exactly that works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally got it!

Yet another stupid mistake, it's not complicated at all, I kept thinking, why I'm having this problem only on this activity, but not my previous one, and I suddenly realized that the layout in the two activities are different, turns out I set the `RecyclerView`'s height to `wrap_content`, so I suppose what happened is that, the layout told the system to wrap the content in the `RecyclerView`, and when you delete an item, it's technically not there anymore, so, even though I have animations for the deleted item, the item is removed immediately from the layout's level, that's why it seems like Android adjusted the `RecyclerView`'s height first, and then delete the item, what actually happened is, since `RecyclerView` is set to `wrap_content`, it removes the position of the view(item) immediately after delete, not after the animation, and that's why it looks like a blink.

Anyways, the solution is just simply to change the `RecyclerView`'s height from `wrap_content` to any other value, if you are using `ConstraintLayout` like I did, just change the height to `0dp`, then constraint the `RecyclerView` to something else, or the edge.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me solve my problem though, I admit this is one of the stupidest yet frustrating problems I ever had.

I believe there're others who also encountered the same problem, so just go and check if the height is set to `wrap_content`.

Comment: I have the same problem, but this solution does not work. But your explanation gave me the hint. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm stuck with the same thing as you. I believe the problem is that CursorLoader restarts every time we delete something from the database, so onLoadFinished is triggering every time and swapping cursors.

The problem can be "solved" if we load our data from the cursor into the List and pass that to the adapter. Still, i find this as a workaround, not a real solution.

Comment: I found the solution, thanks for helping, did you check your layout file and see if the height is set to `wrap_content`? (Check my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Let place the break point at the data object, which bind with the RecyclerViewAdapter and check if the data is blinked or not. In the most of case like this situation, I realize the data maybe is effected and make view change uncontrollable. Because I don't know how you handle the data, so I can't give more detail answers for you.

Comment: Everything is handled by the `cursorLoader`, I was going to post the specific methods that I handle the data, but since the `cursorLoader` 's operation involves too many other classes and methods, I don't really know what should I post on here, can you give me a specific instruction on what should I post here or where to set the break point? Thanks!

Comment: @jackz314 In your RecyclerViewAdapter, place 1 break point at list data object where you declare in this class and 1 more break point at your deleted item method. Then oversee the data, which changes after you delete item. If your list object is changed with strange order, let check your data handle method after delete item, if not check your view handle method in your adapter class.

Comment: @jackz314 Rather than post a bunch of code just add a comment that tells us what you design is. Names of all Classes will help and what class you are executing the delete from. By design I mean MVP where you have specific Classes to handle events and with the RecyclerViewAdapter as you know it needs to work with other classes You might include the names of you XML files

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that, to disable animation?

```
adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Jackz this code below is in the DetailsActivity that has a btnDelete it fires and goes over to DBHelper and deletes the record and returns to DetailsActivity then makes a call to ListActivity to remove the item from the list based on position NOT record ID

```
   private void addListenerOnButtonDelete() {
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Calls the Method deleteDBRow in DatabaseHelper
            // which acts on the TABLE_INFO to remove a record by getting the record ID
            helper.deleteDBRow(String.valueOf(dbList.get(position).getID()));
            ListActivity.removeListRow(position);
            // Code line above calls Method in ListActivity to notify recycler view of changes
            // NOTICE the List keeps items by position not ID <== READ
            etWebSite.setText("");
            etUN.setText("");
            etPW.setText("");
            etSecQuestion.setText("");
            etSecAnswer.setText("");
            etNotes.setText("");

            Intent intent = new Intent(DetailsActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the code that lives in the ListActivity that talks to the Adapter

```
    // This method is called from DetailsActivity and notifies Recycler View that the DB was changed
// and the method makes the same changes to the Recycler View kind of a sync of DB and Recycler View
public static void removeListRow(int position) {
    dbList.remove(position);
    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, dbList.size());
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, please take a look at my update, it seems like the RecyclerView is doing things in wrong order

Comment: @jackz314 So my suggestion is delete the record then remove item from the list then notify with the Adapter the item was removed by position and last with the Adapter do a Item Range Change  as in my code above I also made my list view only show complete items by working on the size of the list view setting the height on the card view that populates the list

Comment: I got the solution, it actually has nothing to do with the actual program process, it's just me being stupid and forgot to set the `RecyclerView`'s height to something other than `wrap_content`, thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I exactly have the same issue and it makes me crazy.

Your solution does not work in my case, probably because my RecyclerViewer is inside a LinearLayout?

The only workaround I found so far is to disable animation like that

```
cardRecyclerView.itemAnimator = null
```

But I really want to re-enable animation since without it is a little bit choppy.

Here is my layout, has someone any idea to avoid the last item blinking when a card is removed? thank you in advance

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.bendk97.platenumber.activities.main.Toolbar"/>
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.bendk97.platenumber.activities.main.SearchBar"/>
    <ProgressBar
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar" android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your solution does not work in my case, probably because my RecyclerViewer is inside a LinearLayout?

Exactly! I pulled it out from LinearLayout and customize RV constraints in the same way as LinearLayout was and after that android:layout_height="0dp" did the trick!

Now the animation is perfectly smooth